# Vsphere image backup software recommandations?

Tags: vmware-vsphere

I'm new to image back up and I'm looking for a back up software for VSphere. Any recommandations?

Comment: "shopping" or "what's the best" questions are discouraged at ServerFault as they tend to not have a definite answer and invite "me too" replies. If you do some research about what's available and have specific questions whether a specific product is a good fit for your environment, you can surely ask here. As is, your question is likely to be closed.

Comment: I see... Sorry, I'm fairly new to this..

Answer (score 1):

Symantec NetBackup, Commvault Simpana, VMWare's own VDR, HP Data Protector, Veeam Backup - there's loads of then, you've provided us with no information to help narrow the market down and we don't do shopping questions.

I hope if you ever post again you can put some actual effort in.